# Programa en c que cuente cuantos pares y nones hay en una string de enteros

Tags: c

```
Tengo este problema donde un determinado valor escaneado lo guardo en una array, despues condiciono con if para que solamente los divisibles entre 2 sean guardados en un array y  y los nones sean guardado en otro pero el problema esta donde intento condicionar a los nonones y no guarda su valor real
```

El problema aparece asi
Se necesita realizar un programa que indique cuantos números pares y cuantos impares existen en un entero dado (E),
(1 <= E <= 1,000,000,000,000,000), se deben mostrar los numero y dentro de corchetes el numero de veces que se
repiten.
Al inicio se debe preguntar cuantos enteros se desean evaluar (N), (1 <= N <= 20).

le resultado tiene que ser
input 123123123
output
pares 2(se repite 3 veces)
nones1 ( se repite 3 veces) 3 (se repite tres veces)

La idea esque tengo que guardar los pares en un array y los nones en otro y tengo que poner la cantidad de veces que se repiten:

```
**#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
int i;
int number;
int digits[10];
int pares[10];
int nones[10];
printf("Ingrese el valor del numero\n");
scanf("%d", &number);
if (number > 0)     // filtro los los vales a mayor a 0
{
    if(number % 2 == 0 )     //   filtro los numeros pares
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)    // llena los arrays 
        {   
        digits[i] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;       
        } 
    else if  (number % 2 == 1)          // filtro los nonoes
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        
        nones[i] = number % 10;       // ya no funciona 
        number = number / 10;
        
        }
        
    }
            
    }   
}
printf("%d\n", digits[0]);
printf("%d\n", digits[1]);
printf("%d\n", digits[2]);

printf("%d\n", digits[0]);
printf("%d\n", digits[1]);
printf("%d\n", digits[2]); 

    return 0;
}
----------**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer punto: No necesitas separar pares e impares. No te están pidiendo el total de pares o el de impares sino el total de cada dígito, presentando los resultados, eso sí, agrupando primero los pares y luego los impares.

Es decir, si tu guardas los totales en un array tal que

```
int digits[10] = {};
//               ^^ no olvidemos inicializar todas las posiciones a 0
```

pues ya está, sabes que la posición 0 se corresponde con el dígito 0 y que la posición 5 almacena el total de `5s` que hay en el número. Para presentar estos resultados basta con hacer dos bucles:

```
printf("pares");
for(int i=0; i<10; i+=2)
{
    if (digits[i] != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d (se repite %d veces)", i, digits[i]);
    }
}

printf(" nones");
for(int i=1; i<10; i+=2)
{
    if (digits[i] != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d (se repite %d veces)", i, digits[i]);
    }
}
```

Y con esto ya tendrías la salida. No hay motivos para complicarse más.

Sin embargo este no sería el mayor de los desafíos en tu código.

Piensa que no tienes que leer números sino caracteres. Si lees un número acabarás leyendo toda la secuencia del tirón. El problema aquí es que necesitas un entero de 64 bits para que te entre el número más alto que te pueden pasar, `1,000,000,000,000,000`, para ello debes usar el tipo `int64_t`. Al no ser un tipo típico, su uso en el código se complica un pelín:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t numero;
scanf("%" SCNd64, &numero);
printf("%" SCNd64, numero);
```

`SCNd64` es una macro que se reemplazará por el código que corresponda, aquí no te vale un `%d` porque estarías limitando la lectura a 32 bits

El caso es que una vez que has leido el número deberías dividir entre 10 para extraer cada dígito por separado y luego comprobar si el dígito es par o impar:

```
while (numero != 0)
{
    int digito = numero % 10;
    numero /= 10;

    digits[digito]++;
}
```

Sin embargo, como he dicho, es más sencillo si lees caracteres:

```
char c;
while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1 && c != '\n')
{
    digits[c-'0']++;
}
```

Comment: Perdón, soy principiante y no logro hacer que compile. Lo primero que hice fue crear el array y lo iguale con 0; int digits[10] = {0};

despues creo que tenemos que convertir los numeros a characteres que es 
char c;
while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
{
    digits[c-'0']++;
}   
sin embargo aquí no logro hacer que se detenga el while, intente cambiar el valor de ==1, a  while(scanf("%c", &c) <= 1)

Comment: @JoseQuiñones perdona, se me olvidó añadir un detalle. Revisa la respuesta